# how to know the db name for ddl in slave server by binlog?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysqlbinlog

In MySQL, the ddl is always statement-based replication.
In the case, the binlog may not contain db name info if a ddl doesn't explicitly contain a db name such as `create table table1` instead of `create table db1.table1`. Then how can the slave server know the right db name and do a right replication.

I don't know if the binlog contains the db name even if the ddl doesn't contain it, or the slave server don't just do replication by binlog.

Comment: Yes the current database is in the binlog. It couldn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

DDL contains db name.

You can use `mysqlbinlog [options] [log_file ...]` commond to read binlog file, for example:`mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000001`.

I created a test_binlog table,

```
CREATE TABLE `test_binlog` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

the binlog like this:

[image]